# Next array element must start off with previous

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array: `['cart', 'registration']`
I want to map him to `['cart', 'cart/registration']`
I tried to do that with .reduce, but prev is just a letter

```
arr.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {  
  let prev = acc[i]
  console.log(prev)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could slice the array and take a subset of the array.

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    result = array.map((_, i, a) => a.slice(0, i + 1).join('/'));

console.log(result);
```

Or store the last value

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    result = array.map((last => v => last += (last && '/') + v)(''));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` isn't the right tool for this. A simple loop (in any of the varied forms it can take) is. Here's the `for` loop version:

```js
const array = ['cart', 'registration', 'third'];
for (let i = 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
  array[i] = array[i - 1] + "/" + array[i];
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

`acc` is the value returned by the previous accumulator, or in the first iteration it is either the initial value passed as a second argument to `.reduce` or if no initial value is passed the iteration will start with the second element and the first element gets passed as `acc`. Thats what happens in your case, so `acc` is `"cart"`, `curr` is `"registration"`, `i` is 1, and therefore `acc[i]` is `"cart"[1]` which is `"a"`. Just take `acc` as a whole instead.

```
  const result = [arr[0]];

  arr.reduce((acc, cur, i) => result[i] = acc + "/" + cur);
```